# How to get Google Sheets to show a sort by column UX?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

**NOTE**: This question is **NOT** about how to sort rows by selecting them and then choosing Data->Sort Range

Rather, I want to know if it's possible to add or enable a UX here there's a sort button on each column's heading

Here's what the top of my sheet looks like now

[image]

And here is what I want it to look something like, each column having a button that sorts by that column

[image]

Note: I'm not looking for a scripting solution (I'm sure I could write that). I'm asking, is there some basic feature I can use that will provide a UX where I can trivially sort by column? I feel like this is probably one of those basic features that lots of people use and I'm embarrassed I don't know how to enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in function that does that is called "Create a filter"

Click on the menu Data > Create filter or on the Google Sheets toolbar look for the funnel icon and click on it.

[image]

[image]

Resource

- [Sort & filter your data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en)